# why the finger getting folded

Tags: rigging

Im rigging a hand. Whats wrong with the rigging the finger are getting folded and mix with each other.

[image]

[image]

I tried weight paint also but did not work. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in a misalignment between the deforming bones and the mesh, so you will have to adapt them one to another (actually, it seems to me far more easy to modify the mesh than this complicated rig).

[image]

Comment: I have used the blenrig addon for rigging. With the alignment with the stick it was looking good. As you have switch to bone looking miss alignment. Is there any quick way to rig and make control as i have show above with the controller to fold the hand in good way. Thanks